# disabling button when input field is empty not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, button

I am trying to disable my download button when the field is empty, when the user types the name only it should show. because without entering text also the user is able to download image. I have done the following code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">




<div class="container">
  <div style="margin-top: 5%; " class="row">

    <?php
            require('db_config.php');
$id=$_GET['editid'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery where id='$id'";
            $images = $mysqli->query($sql);


            while($image = $images->fetch_assoc()){


            ?>
      <div style="margin-left: 5%;" class="col-md-5"><canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas></div>




      <div style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 10%;" class="col-md-5 col-sm-8">


        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="something"><span class="sims">Card Name: &nbsp</span>
              <?php echo $image['title']; ?>
            </h4>
            <div class="modal-body">


              <form method="post" action="" id="form_name">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input class="lolan" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required />
                    <!-- <label for="name" class="form__label">Full Name</label> -->
                  </div>
                  <div id="chumma" class="col-md-12">

                    <button id="download" type="submit" onclick="download_image()" name="button" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>


                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>



            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

  </div>
</div>





<script type="text/javascript">
  var text_title = "Heading";

  var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  // img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  window.addEventListener('load', DrawPlaceholder)

  function DrawPlaceholder() {
    img.onload = function() {
      DrawOverlay(img);
      DrawText(text_title);
      DynamicText(img)
    };
    img.src = 'uploads/<?php echo $image['
    image '];?>';

  }

  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.height = 500;


  function DrawOverlay(img) {

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(230, 14, 14, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  function DrawText(text) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.font = "50px 'Montserrat'";
    ctx.fillText(text, 150, 250);
  }

  function DynamicText(img) {
    document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      DrawOverlay(img);
      text_title = this.value;
      DrawText(text_title);
    });
  }


  function download_image() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
    image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = "my-image.png";
    link.href = image;
    link.click();
  }
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    validate();
    $('#name').change(validate);
  });

  function validate() {
    if ($('#name').val().length > 0 && {
        $("#download").prop("disabled", false);
      }
      else {
        $("#download").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    }
</script>


<?php } ?>
```

but this is not making the button from disabling when the input is empty. can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has some syntax errors and you should use `keyup` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    validate();
    $('#name').keyup(validate);
});

function validate() {
    if ($('#name').val().length > 0) {
        $("#download").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#download").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name">
<button id="download">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed 2 things in your JavaScript code:

`$('#name').change(validate);` is triggered only when you exit (blur) the field.
Instead, you can use:
`$('#name').keyup(validate);`

There's a syntax error at:
`if ($('#name').val().length > 0 && {`
You should close the parenthesis like:
`if ($('#name').val().length > 0 ) {`

Hope this helps!